# iPhone 3.0 beta - what effects does it have on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I am currently developing applications on the 2.2.1 sdk, and considering to upgrading my iphone to sdk 3.0. Can my phone still be used to run old version programs (2.1, 2.2 etc), call, send sms and so on? Or will it be restricted to only be used to test 3.0 developed programs?
Thanks, Hans Espen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple has frozen iPhone development on v2.2 for the past few weeks.  All new apps submitted to the App Store have to be on v3 of the OS.

Your phone will still be able to run all your existing apps, and all core services will function.  Beware that the OS will be considered Beta and will expire after 30 days.  The expiration will require you to download the latest SDK and refresh your device.  Not a problem, just an annoyance.

The v3 of the OS is likely to go from beta to generally available during WWDC on Monday (06.08.09), so it may be easier to just wait till then if you do not want to deal with some of the beta hassles.

Comment: I understand they are to be tested on v3, I remember seeing somewhere apple stating that the app must be tested and compatible with v3.0 but needs to be built on v2.2 - Has this changed now?

Comment: Apple is only accepting applications that have been built and tested on v3 of the OS.  They communicated his to all members of the Developer program via e-mail and on the Developer Connection on May 7th.

Comment: built and tested on OS 3.0 but using the 2.2 SDK I think, actually - right?

Answer (score 3):

The part about "built ... on v3.0" is wrong. Your application does not need to "compilable on v3.0". Apple has never said anything about applications compiled on 2.x not being accepted now, or at any future date.  In fact, if you submit an application built against the v3.0 SDK, it will be rejected.  v3.0 is still in beta, you are not to build applications destined for the App Store with it.  Apple says as much in the email that was referenced, and in the "Getting Ready" doc: "*Do not submit applications to iTunes Connect that have 
been built using the iPhone OS 3.0 beta SDK.*"

What you **are** to do is test your 2.x application running on v3.0.  Apple has explicit instructions on what you are to do here: http://adcdownload.apple.com/iphone/important_information_about_iphone_os_3.0_compatibility/important_information_about_iphone_os_3.0_compatibility_1.pdf

As to Hans question, what you are wanting to do is exactly what Apple wants you to do:  build your 2.x applications, and test them on your v3.0 phone, following the instructions linked above.

As for your phone's functionality on v3.0, all I can say is that mine works fine, if a little slow at times.  2.x apps work (those that are compatible, anyway), and all functionality is there.

Answer (score 1):

If you download the 3.0 SDK beta, install it on your device, then you are restricted to only 3.0 SDK development on that device. As far as I know if you have a device with SDK 2.2 and SDK 3.0 you should be able to test your application on both, but as MystikSpiral mentioned Apple has frozen submissions and they are requiring them to be compilable on the 3.0 SDK.

At this point with WWDC next week you should be testing any applications you have on a 3.0 device. It looks like the final build of 3.0 will be released next week alongside a new iteration of the hardware (all signs point to it).